# Pair together two arrays in PHP after posting from two fields in a form

Tags: php, html, arrays, append, field

I have two fields in a form (ip:port) seperately. I want to add them together to make one string eg 127.0.0.1:11111 to enter into a database. At the moment I have this form.

```
        <ul id="textlist">
            <li>IP: <input type="text" maxlength="15" size="15" name="ip[]" value="" />:<input type="text" name="port[]" maxlength="5" size="5" value="27015" /></li>
        </ul>
```

Which submits to this for parsing.

```
$ip = array();
foreach ($_POST['ip'] as &$value) {
    if ($value != "") {
            if (preg_match("/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/", $value)) {
                $ip[] = addslashes(htmlentities($value));
            } else {
                $error = 'Invalid IP Address. Please go back and try again.';
            }
    }
}

$port = array();
foreach ($_POST['port'] as &$value) {
        if ($value != "") {
                $port[] = addslashes(htmlentities($value));
        }
    }
}
```

I then end up with 2 arrays of ip's and ports (up to 5 of each) which I want to join together in pairs before adding to a database.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = 0
$ip_port = array();
foreach ($_POST['ip'] as &$value) {
    if ($value != "") {
            if (preg_match("/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/", $value)) {
                $ip_port[$x++]['ip'] = addslashes(htmlentities($value));
            } else {
                $error = 'Invalid IP Address. Please go back and try again.';
            }
    }
}

$x = 0
foreach ($_POST['port'] as &$value) {
        if ($value != "") {
                $ip_port[$x++]['port'] = addslashes(htmlentities($value));
        }
    }
}

foreach ($ip_post as $curr) {
    echo "{$curr['ip']}:{$curr['port']}";
}
```

this will work as long as your arrays are perfectly parallel.  you might consider adding numeric indexes to your HTML form instead of depending on ordering.

Comment: Ok the arrays will always be parallel, but ill consider changing it anyway for the sake of reliability.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to add numeric indexes to HTML, just to be sure you have correct pairs.

```
<ul id="textlist">
    <li>IP: <input type="text" maxlength="15" size="15" name="ip[0]" value="" />:<input type="text" name="port[0]" maxlength="5" size="5" value="27015" /></li>
    <li>IP: <input type="text" maxlength="15" size="15" name="ip[1]" value="" />:<input type="text" name="port[1]" maxlength="5" size="5" value="27015" /></li>
</ul>
```

After that, you can do it safely in one loop.

```
$pairs = array();
foreach ( $_POST['ip'] as $i => $ip ) 
{
    if ( preg_match("/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/", $ip) && $_POST['port'][$i] != "" ) 
    {
        $pairs[] = sprintf('%s:%s', addslashes(htmlentities($value)), addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['port'][$i])));
    } 
}
```

It would be wise to add some additional error checking, for example checking if `$_POST['port'][$i]` is set, its value etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make life a lot easier on yourself by reformatting your form a bit.  You can either give your ip and port fields explicit indexes instead of relying on the [] behaviour, or you can bundle each ip and port together into a subfield of a bigger array.

(attributes and other stuff not essential to the example has been omitted in the examples below)

Option a:

```
<li><input name="ip[1]" />: <input name="port[1]" /></li>
<li><input name="ip[2]" />: <input name="port[2]" /></li>
<li><input name="ip[3]" />: <input name="port[3]" /></li>
<!-- etc -->
```

This should return two arrays, an IP array and a Port array, with the index of each line being the same.  You can then use `foreach ($ip as $key => $val)` and use the value in $key to get the corresponding value out of the Port array.

Option b:

```
<li><input name="connection[][ip]" />: <input name="connection[][port]" /></li>
<li><input name="connection[][ip]" />: <input name="connection[][port]" /></li>
<li><input name="connection[][ip]" />: <input name="connection[][port]" /></li>
<!-- etc -->
```

This should return a single array, with each row consisting of an IP and port bundled together.  You can then just foreach over the array.

```
foreach ($connection as $row)
{
    var_dump ($row ['ip'], $row ['port']);
}
```